# capture STDOut from already running process in c#

Tags: c#, console-application, stdout, stderr

Lets say I have some kind of console app currently running, **not** started by my app. (Could be a cmd.exe or some sort of console app)

How do I get my app to read all the text (stdout/stderr) in inside that app?